# Android USB connection established only the second time the app is opened

Tags: android, usb

For my application, I need to establish a connection with an attached Arduino device, here is the code:

```
public String openConnection(UsbManager manager, Context context) {

    // getting the driver with an external library...

    UsbSerialDriver driver = availableDrivers.get(0);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    manager.requestPermission(driver.getDevice(), pi);

    UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(driver.getDevice());

    if (connection == null) {
        return "Found a device, but cannot connect";
    }

    // otherwise, continue and do stuff
}
```

The problem is that, when a device is attached, the first time I open the app it shows the alert asking for the permission, but if I click "OK", the connection is null, so it returns early. However, the second time it does not ask for any permission but the connection is opened and everything works fine.

Why does this happen?

I know this is not the most correct approach to open an USB connection, but I have other issues that are not inherent to the question, so I'm rather intrested to understand *why* does this happen than *what* should I do instead

I'm testing this on Android 8.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to previously ask for permission and start the rest of your code from a Broadcast Receiver that listens for the USB permission granted.
This is showed in Google's docs:

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
"com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
        synchronized (this) {
            UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                if(device != null){
                  //call method to set up device communication
               }
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

Here's how you register the Broadcast Receiver:

```
UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) 
getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
"com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
...
mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new 
Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

And then you start it all with:

```
UsbDevice device;
...
mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
```

In the way you do it, the device tries to connect to USB even before the permission has been granted and so it fails.

Comment: As I said, I know that mine was not the most correct approach and I checked the google docs but I have other issues and I would prefer to try to make that works with minimum modifications if possibiles. Anyway, I first call requestPermission and then openDevice, so why do you say that " the device tries to connect to USB even before the permission has been granted"?

Comment: I say that because requestPermission is not a blocking function call, it only opens the dialog for the permission request and then the code goes on executing. So openDevice will be executed immediately as well, without you having time to grant the permission. I know that this looks like too much overhead but this process has been engineered to be executed with a Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: Also this comes from Google's description: "When users reply to the dialog, your broadcast receiver receives the intent that contains the EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED extra, which is a boolean representing the answer. Check this extra for a value of true before connecting to the device."

Comment: Thank you, so the key is that requestPermission is non-blocking and If I understand this correctly, the first time, when it get permission, it has already returned, while the second time since the permission is previously given, there are no more need to ask and everything works fine.

Comment: Yes, exactly, when openDevice checks the permission the second time, it finds it already granted and it works well ;)